# React JS is inserting the style of all my components in the app, CSS modules

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am using the latest ReactJS with Create React App + Typescript, and I am using CSS modules. The App architecture would be:

```
/components
   SignIn/
      SignIn.module.scss
      SignIn.tsx
   ResetPassword/
      ResetPassword.module.scss
      ResetPassword.tsx
```

Inside each FC component, I include the CSS like this:

**SignIn Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './SignIn.module.scss';

const SignIn: React.FC = props => { 
    ... 
    return {
       <div className={styles.container} />
    }
}
...
```

**ResetPassword Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ResetPassword.module.scss';

const ResetPassword: React.FC = props => { 
    ... 
    return {
       <div className={styles.card} />
    }
}
...
```

I define `react-router-dom` like this...

```
   ...
   <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
             <Route path='/sing-in' component={SignIn} />
             <Route path='/reset-password' component={ResetPassword} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    ...
```

**The issue:**

React inserts the `<style>` of each component regardless if I am in the `Sign-in` page or in the `reset-password` page.

**Expected behaviour:**

React inserts **only** the CSS for the component displaying in the current page.

I have tried to add the prop `exact` in each `Route` but it didn't work.

Comment: There are ways to accomplish code-splitting.  Have you checked the docs: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/code-splitting

Comment: Hi, @DavinTryon I have tried using `@loadable/component` for code-splitting. It works fine, and load only the CSS for that page, but it does not remove the inserted CSS when the component unmounts or does not remove the previous CSS when I navigate to another page. :(